# Github: How to prevent a merge if package.json version hasn't been icnreased

Tags: github, hook

I'm working in an **Open Source project**, and I want to **prevent a merge** to `master` branch if the `package.json version` **hasn't been increased**.

To do so, I've been reading about `git hooks`, but I'm not sure what's the way to prevet the merge comparing the master branch package.json version and the source branch package.json version.

I don't know how would I share client-side hooks with any new collaborator since the client-side hooks doesn't live in the repository, and I don't find the way to add a server-side hook to a github repo.

I'm neither sure what would be the appropiate hook to do this, I think `pre-merge-commit` would be the best way, but I'm not sure about that since it is a client-side hook.

Some idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same question, did you find out the answer?

Comment: @Triguna I didn't find the way to prevent the merge to main. I created a file'check-version.js', throwing error if the version hasn't been incremented. That file is called before test, build and publishing the package. In this way I don't have to wait the whole CD queue to know the package version is wrong.